# Store words in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-limit

I am making an SQLite database in Android in which i have to store 40k words in it. I am getting the words from q txt file.

I am storing the words first in a list and then from list to database. But when I store words in table and retrieve from that i get only 20k words. The rowcount of the table is also 20k but i have saved 40k words.

```
public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, ArrayList<String> words)
{
    int i=0;


        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        System.out.println("created table going further");

        for( i=0; i < words.size();i++)
        {
            String[] pair=words.get(i).split(",");

            insertWord(pair[0].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[1].trim()), db);
            System.out.println(i++);            
        }
        System.out.println("in database  "+i+" words are there in db");     
}
```

I don't know whats going on here.

Comment: do you have uniqness constraints? are you sure you have saved all 40k words? what happens with much less words (like 10)? which words are missing (random, all the last, all the first, every other one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` **twice**, one in the for and one in the print statement, change this to

```
for( i=0; i < words.size();i++)
    {
        String[] pair=words.get(i).split(",");

        insertWord(pair[0].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[1].trim()), db);
        System.out.println(i);            
    }
```